# how to redirect url on helicon

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, isapi, isapi-redirect, helicontech

I'm just getting into helicon , so forgive me if this is a basic question. my asp.net website contain bellow fixed urls.want to redirect this fixed url to my defined fixed  url.

```
Base URL=http://www.abc.ca/category/233/incontinence  
Redirect URL=http://www.abc.ca/browse/652/free_wipes
```

In my asp.net website,I use helicon to redirect url ,I need help on helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file,I need a rule that redirect  my rules.When only my base url appear I want helicon redirect this url to above Redirect URL page.

if have any query plz ask,thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with ThinkingMonkey, but I'd apply the following in your site's .htaccess(as you need the 301-redirect, I assume):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category/233/incontinence$ /browse/652/free_wipes [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [ISAPI_Rewrite<sup>docs</sup>](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/) is similar to mod_rewrite. Hence giving it a try.

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^category/233/incontinence/? browse/652/free_wipes [NC,R=301,L]
```